Porque el compilador realiza cambios en los colores de hex a rgba? Gulp Tasks
Instale una extencion llamada Gulp Tasks, cuando lo ejecuto para generar mi archivo minificado, el resultado es diferente, cambia los colores de transparent a rgba y otros mas como en el ejemplo


test.scss

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 0.51em; 
}

// -----------------------------------

test.min.css

body{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);width:.51em}



texto en negrita

Algun heroe sin capa..

A no ser que necesites compatibilidad con navegadores muy viejos... rgba(0,0,0,0) es exactamente lo mismo que transparent. Por qué lo cambia?? Pues tendrás que preguntarle a quien diseñó el compilador si no está en la documentación.

transparent es un alias para un negro con opacidad cero: rgb(0,0,0,0) (como se especifica en el estándar de CSS. Eso explicaría el cambio, pero no tiene mucho sentido cambiarlo en un archivo minificado, que se supone que debe ser más pequeño. Quizás para proporcionar mayor soporte a navegadores antiguos como menciona Benito-B (por eso también usaría rgba en vez de rgb), de lo contrario, usar #0000 sería considerablemente más corto.

Más allá de eso, esta pregunta no termina de ajustarse bien al formato y contenido del sitio.
